# Getting the button control from the pop over controller ios

Tags: ios, uiview, properties, uibutton, uipopovercontroller

My iOS app has 13 buttons on a single view controller. Clicking on each of them opens a popovercontroller. Not all at once. Apple rule, i know. You click one  you make selection and then dismiss it and do it for the other buttons and keep going. Now i have a delegate which tells me what option i chose on the popovers. Like Button1 popovervalues-( 1,2,3) Button2 popovervalues- (a,b,c).Now the method in delegate tells me that 1 was chosen or a was chosen. But it doesnt tell me Button1 was clicked or button2. I want to know how can i get button control name/or just the button for now would suffice. Is there any property from which i can tell which was the button clicked? I saw contentviewcontroller, inputview, navigationcontroller etc for the popovercontroller.But neither help me get to the button that was clicked. I want to know that because if option 1 was chosen in the popover for the Button1 then i have to disable Button10. So knowing what option on what button was selected will simplify the user selection (its a requirement actually). Please let me know if more information is needed. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting the buttons via interface builder?
if so, then it should be connected via an IBAction method.

```
- (IBAction)someAction:(id)sender {
   UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;
   //Now you have the button you have pressed
}
```

If you made the button programmatically and added the target to it
N.B the colon after someAction in the selector bit

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

You can use the same method as before with the IBAction, or you can make your own void method, either way, the sender is the button, just need to cast it then use it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @mashdup.Thanks.I should have made myself more clear. My set up is like this                                                            -(IBAction)btnBCoverClick:(UIButton *)sender
{ 
 NSArray *tempArray =[self GetChildCodes : S_B_C]; 
 [self ShowPopOver : tempArray ButtonPass:sender];
}
  Now i have a delegate that will eventually call this method            -(void)optionSelected:(NSString *)option
{
 NSLog(@"the value selected is %@",option); 
}.Inside this method(called by delegate) i want to know which button was clicked.I have 12 more button actions.If more info is needed tell me.Thanks.

Comment: why dont you pass the button back, you passed it to the popover, why not pass it back to optionselected:(nsstring*)option withButton:(UIButton*)passedButton {...

Answer (score 0):

Use the tag value of the button.  Set a number and check for it in the action method:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
   UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;
   if(buttonPressed.tag == 1) {
        //Do this
   }
}
```

Comment: @Dancreek.Thanks.I should have made myself more clear. My set up is like this                                                            -(IBAction)btnBCoverClick:(UIButton *)sender
{ 
 NSArray *tempArray =[self GetChildCodes : S_B_C]; 
 [self ShowPopOver : tempArray ButtonPass:sender];
}
  Now i have a delegate that will eventually call this method            -(void)optionSelected:(NSString *)option
{
 NSLog(@"the value selected is %@",option); 
}.Inside this method(called by delegate) i want to know which button was clicked.I have 12 more button actions.If more info is needed tell me.Thanks.